# RestKit , PUT complex JSON to server

Tags: json, restkit, restkit-0.20

the request json i want to PUT to server

```
"type": "payment",
"paymentOptions": [
    {
        "type": "netbanking",
        "name": "NetBanking - AXIS Bank",
        "expiryDate": null,
        "bank": "AXIS Bank"
    }
]
```

class for mapping

```
@interface CTSPaymentDetailUpdate : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString* type;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSMutableArray* paymentOptions;

@interface CTSPaymentOption : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString* type, *ownerName, *number, *bankName, *expiryDate;
```

code for mapping

```
  #define MLC_PROFILE_UPDATE_PAYMENT_REQUEST_MAPPING \
@{                                               \
@"type" : @"type",                             \
@"bank" : @"bankName",                         \
@"owner" : @"ownerName",                       \
@"number" : @"number",                         \
@"expiryDate" : @"expiryDate",                 \
@"name" : @"cardName"                          \
}

  RKObjectMapping* paymentOptionMapping =
  [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CTSPaymentOption class]];
  [paymentOptionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
                        MLC_PROFILE_UPDATE_PAYMENT_REQUEST_MAPPING];

  RKObjectMapping* paymentDetailReq = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
  [paymentDetailReq addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"type" : @"type" }];
  [paymentDetailReq
  addPropertyMapping:
      [RKRelationshipMapping
          relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"paymentOptions"
                               toKeyPath:@"paymentOptions"
                             withMapping:paymentOptionMapping]];

  RKRequestDescriptor* requestDes = [RKRequestDescriptor
  requestDescriptorWithMapping:paymentDetailReq
                   objectClass:[CTSPaymentDetailUpdate class]
                   rootKeyPath:nil
                        method:[self getHTTPMethodFor:PUT]];
  [objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDes];
```

once i use following to actually put the object to server

```
[objectManager putObject:object
  path:path
  parameters:queryParams
  success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation* operation,
            RKMappingResult* mappingResult) {
//code
}
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error) {
    //code  
  }];
```

i get NSUnknownKeyException on this line
`2014-06-22 11:12:22.587 RestFulltester[1727:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CTSPaymentOption 0x10bf2ae80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key owner.'`

i think there is something wrong with the the way i have made the mapping but i am not able to understand,also is there any way to test the json that this code will produce beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
withMapping:paymentOptionMapping]];
```

when creating your relationship mapping should be:

```
withMapping:[paymentOptionMapping inverseMapping]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
[session.objectManager requestWithObject:object 
                                  method:RKRequestMethodPUT 
                                    path:queryPath
                              parameters:params]
```

Comment: I've added another possible solution.

Comment: how will it detect the json keys?

Comment: Because I've added your `RKRequestDescriptor` with the waiting keyPath.

Comment: a waiting keypath ... what does that mean ? i dont see anything like that in your code...

Comment: I mean your waiting JSON schema. In your case there is not root key (that's why you put `rootKeyPath:nil`. Then you describe your request and add it to the objectManager. Finally you send the request with your object, its type etc.

Comment: so you mean to instead of using putObject method i should just get the NSMutable request from above function and fire it

Comment: but then i have a very complex json coming in response , i want to avoid manual mapping